# in .NET, references must be added for project to compile but intellisense (and resharper) seems fine without them

Tags: .net, compilation, reference

It's a peculiar thing in .NET; References to dlls must sometimes be added for a project to compile but intellisense seems fine without them. Even resharper doesn't detect any errors.
For instance, I just had to go through and references to System.Web even though nothing on my project called it directly.
Is this because a reference might be referencing it? Should it just copy the dll and handle it on its own?
What am I missing?

Comment: Tends to happen when your target framework is _client profile_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look closely - from what I usually see, only *part* of it appears. I believe this is because the namespace is defined in a referenced DLL, but only part of it is implemented, in a way - the parts implemented in the DLL. An assembly is *not* the same as a namespace, and it will contain only what it needs to function. I think you'll find it impossible to, say, load XML documents through `System.Xml` without a reference to `System.Xml.dll`.